# What is "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 19019?

Tags: https

When I am trying to run a project based on python then it appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that a HTTP GET request was made to `/` (the first forward slash) and 200 means it was succesfull. 200 is a http response code, check this link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Good luck!

Comment: Not really a meaning in the sense that it is a code or anything. So can't tell you the meaning of it, sorry.